# nginx 1.6.2 [Windows] won't find protected directory

Tags: html, .htaccess, nginx, password-protection, .htpasswd

as the headline said, my nginx isn't able to find .htpasswd-protected directories. Here are my settings, my .conf and the locations of the relevant files:

*NOTE: due to my brothers wish, the nginx runs on a win8.1x32 virtual machine*

I created a .htaccess file in my root/xx directory looking like this:

```
AuthName "Restricted Area"
AuthType Basic
AuthUserFile /b/.htpasswd
AuthGroupFile /dev/null
require valid-user
```

And I created a .htpasswd file inside the shown directory.
After that I modified my .conf in the conf-folder like this:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
include       mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;


sendfile        on;

keepalive_timeout  65;

server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

location ^~ /b/ {
    auth_basic          "Restricted Area";
    auth_basic_user_file    b/htpasswd;
}
}
```

I deleted the comment-lines from the auto-generated file only here, in the original, they are still existent - thought this might clear your sight on the file.

Now, here comes the problem: the file which I am aiming for is called int.html and can be found in /b/int.html (stylesheets and scriptfiles included), but every time i want to get to this file, the browser asks my to type in password and username - as I wanted it - but then the browser shows a 404-error, which means, he couldn't find the named file. (I made sure everything is spelled correct in the directories and tried this in several browsers on different devices). I don't know why. (I already tried to set the int.html as index in the config like this:

```
location ^~ /b/ {
auth_basic          "Restricted Area";
auth_basic_user_file    b/htpasswd;    
}
```

But it still doesn't work. - Ideas, anyone?

Greetz Dyarn

Comment: You don't define `root`, so nginx uses default, which is completely useless here. _Always_ define `root` in server block.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I inserted the root-specifier like this: `root html/b;`, but it did not changed the problem, I guess.

Comment: Use absolute full path like `root /var/www/path/to/html;`. Relative path resolved as relative to `/etc/nginx` or something like that.

Comment: "absolute" and "relative" paths doesn't look the same in Windows- and unix-systems, doesn't they? In the Windows-explorer I can extract the paths, this path doesn't look like the one you gave as an example. Is it possible, that I chose the wrong directory for the .htpasswd-file? - atm it is in the html/b/ directory, which is also the one I want to lock. (or maybe I typed the wrong path into the server block of the .conf?)

Comment: All path should be absolute. Nginx has quite strange default path so in order to avoid it always use absolute paths in nginx.

Comment: BTW, nginx on windows should not be used for production server. http://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html

Comment: Yea, okay, I'll do what I can to convince my brother to migrate to UNIX-based operating systems. - The path-thing will work for me on unix? (Do you think a proper new setup of an nginx will solve my problem?)

Comment: It should. I just noticed that you've missed dot in `.htpasswd`

Comment: Oh, yes, thanks - I'd never found this by myself... - Tomorrow I'll switch the OS and reset my nginx completely (there is not much on it yet, so it should take about 4 hours to set things up), I will report if it works.

Comment: Okay, i succesfully migrated to Ubuntu - but now I've got two problems: none of my sites will display their background anymore (did not change anything in the html-code or of the picture locations); the security log still won't work - neither the "/var/..."-paths nor the "/etc/..."-paths will work. any ideas?

Comment: EDIT: the error page now not longer shows an 404-error, but an 403-error (forbidden)...